# Vim less than sign?

Tags: vim

I found how to compile the current buffer in vim with make:

```
set makeprg=g++\ -o\ %<\ %
```

I know that `%` means "current buffer" but I am wondering what less than sign (`<`) means?

Also, in this link http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make-compile_current_buffer mentions that `%<` is deprecated. Is there another way?

Comment: You can make it more readable with `:let &makeprg='g++ -o %< %'` (if you need to insert a single quote, double it. Otherwise everything is literally interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"%<" is expanded to the name of the current buffer without the extension. See `:help _%<`.
So, when you are currently editing myfile.c, your `makeprg` setting is expanded to `g++ -o myfile myfile.c`, which will compile myfile.c into the executable `myfile`.

Answer (score 3):

It's defining a command called makeprg which calls g++. The < is just standard notation in most shells to pipe the contents of the current file into the process, so it will pipe (well, more formally, redirect stdin) to the current buffer. In other words, it'll compile the current buffer.